# Use a value from another query in a query

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have query 1 which has a result with one row and one column, it shows the period our system is in.

I want to use that value from query 1 in another query called query 2

So for example it would be something like

```
Select * FROM MyTable WHERE Period = (Period in Query 1)
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: and can you post the tables, so we can have an idea the data we are dealing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery for this so:

```
Select * FROM MyTable WHERE Period = (
 SELECT period FROM someothertable WHERE ...)
```

There are numerous other ways of doing this however, so it would need research and testing to find the most efficient way.

Comment: Thanks George, what would be some other ways I could try?

Comment: @danieldunn10 ... is this homework?

Comment: @danieldunn10 I'm not going to Google that for you - there are a number of resources available online and you'd do well to learn how to research stuff like this yourself - it's a skill in itself.